# How to make Grid to be changed number of columns according to network data in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am getting column data from my json and I want to set that column number to `GridArray(count: data.column)` so it will be dynamic. But I couldn't find a solution for that. İ tried to lazy variable but it didn't work either.

```
struct ListTypeShow : View {
    var data : ShowCaseData
    var columnsGrid = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 20), count: 4)
    
    var body: some View {
        switch data.type {
        case ListType.vertical.rawValue:
            LazyVGrid(columns: columnsGrid, spacing:30 ) {
                ForEach(data.options! , id :\.id ) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                        Image(uiImage:(item.image ?? "").load())
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(CGFloat(data.ratio ?? 1),contentMode: .fit)
                            .padding(.horizontal , 5)
                    }
                }
            }
        default:
            Text("Deneme")
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm calling `View` in here ;

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(productListData, id:\.id) { item in
                    if item.success == true {
                        ForEach(showCaseData , id:\.id) { data in
                            ListTypeShow(data: data)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: $isAnimating)
    }
    .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            getStoreIndex()
        }
    }
}
```

How can I set `data.column` to `Count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your view depend on column changes, You have to make column as @State ,
check this demo.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var column = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 20), count: 4)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                //like here, you can change the column after you get json data
                column = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 20), count: Int.random(in: 1...10))
            }, label: {
                Text("Change column")
            })
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: column,spacing: 30,content: {
                ForEach(0 ..< 9) { item in
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```